# Remove CSS priority from stylesheets

Tags: css, pagespeed

I follow this recommendation from [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent):

> This may mean that you must split your CSS into two parts: an inline part that is responsible for styling the ATF portion of the content, and the part that can be deferred.

I already calculated the CSS needed to render the above-the-fold content. However the external stylesheets contains the already inlined CSS. I need a way to include an external stylesheet with the only required CSS to render the rest of the page, as Google recommends.

My best guess is:

1. Load the CSS from the external stylesheets
2. Filter each selector from the CSS priority in the stylesheet
3. Produce a new stylesheet with the non-matching CSS of #2

How can I achieve #2? Or other approach to remove the already inlined CSS from the external stylesheets?

Comment: If the above-the-fold styles are now inline, do you need them in the external style sheet at all? Could you not simply delete those duplicated lines?

Comment: @DBS I don't need it, I want to delete it from the external stylesheets. Is not  clear in the question?

Comment: Yes, I need. The HTML and CSS is stored as a variable in a PHP Code. I can use node js too.